# Defining supermanifolds by equations

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, superalgebra, supermanifolds, supergeometry

I would like to in what sense supermanifolds may be defined by systems of equations in the ordinary flat superspace. I am particularly interested in the approach to supergeometry via ringed spaces.

Remark: situation is quite clear for me in the case of affine super schemes. In this case subscheme of the spectrum $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal A)$ of the supercommutative superalgebra $\mathcal A$ which may be described as the zero locus of an ideal $J \subseteq \mathcal A$ is simply the spectrum of the supercommutative superalgebra $\frac{\mathcal A}{J}$. We have a canonical morphism $\mathrm{Spec} \left (\frac{\mathcal A}{J} \right ) \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal A)$. This construction doesn't seem to easily generalize to supermanifolds.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a super ringed space is a pair $X= (|X|, \mathcal{O}_X)$ consisting of a topological space $|X|$   and  a sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of supercommutative algebras over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Supermanifolds are glued together from local models, usually $\mathbb{C}^{m|n}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{m|n}$ which are both super ringed space. This is analogous to superschemes being locally modeled by affine superschemes.

The superspace $\mathbb{C}^{m|n} = (\mathbb{C}^m, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{m|n}})$ is a super ringed space with a sheaf of supercommutative algebras, 
$$ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{m|n}}: U \to \operatorname{Hol}(U) \otimes \bigwedge \theta_i$$ 
where $\operatorname{Hol}(U)$ is the ordinary algebra of holomorphic functions on an open subset $U$ and $\theta_i$ are a choice of $n$ odd indeterminates. Clearly, $\operatorname{Hol}(U) \otimes \bigwedge \theta_i$ is a supercommutative algebra.

In this case, one may view the odd indeterminates $\theta_i$ as generators of a rank $n$ vector bundle $V$ over the ordinary manifold $\mathbb{C}^m$.  Any such vector bundle is locally free and thus we know exactly how the $\theta_i$ glue together. You will sometimes see $\operatorname{Hol}(U) \otimes \bigwedge \theta_i$ denoted simply by $\bigwedge V^*$.

You can now think of supermanifolds as being cut out locally by the vanishing sets of (super) functions $f \in \operatorname{Hol}(U) \otimes \bigwedge \theta_i$.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Suppose that we are given some set of polynomial equations $f(z, \theta)=0$ for some $f \in \mathrm{Hol}(\mathbb C^n) \otimes \bigwedge \theta_i$. How do we construct the supermanifold described as the zero locus of $f$? Am I right to think that (as a set) it is simply the submanifold $f(z,0)=0$ (odd generators ignored here), but equipped with some extra structure: sheaf of supercommutative algebras, whose properties reflect the way $\theta$ appear in the equation $f(z, \theta)$. What are the conditions for $f$ which assure that such a construction is possible?